# JAXB UnmarshalException - Filename containing #

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

**SCENARIO**

I am using JAXB 2.0, and I had a process that receive xml files from a webservice that need to be unmarshalled. Names are provided by webservice and with format:

```
ESA08021701#99152015AA00024175#20150612#20150618125838_NOTIF_250073.xml
```

**PROBLEM**

When I try to unmarshall this files:

```
File file = // get my file from a list
unmarshaller.unmarshal(file);
```

I get this `UnmarshalException`

> javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>   - with linked exception:
>   [java.io.**FileNotFoundException: ESA08021701** (The system cannot find the file specified.)]
>        at javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException.(UnmarshalException.java:56)

I've notticed the filename in `Exception` is not complet `ESA08021701`, but debugging I can see filename is correct and `File` exists...

**QUESTION**

Is this a bug? AFAIK `#` is not a special character for filenames? How can I process this files?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After researching in documentation and forums, I guess this still is a `JaxB` problem, but finally I found a workaround with `FileInputStream` for this that can be useful for others:

```
File file = // get my file from a list
Object unmarshalled = unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileInputStream(myFile));
```